# How to light a scene with a skybox as background and have a HDRi or sun in the world environment?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, hdri, skybox

How can I have a Skybox object that works as background all around my scene but also have a HDRi or Sun to produce ambient light?. In my current setup the Skybox blocks the HDRi or Sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a mesh for the "skybox", all you need to do is make the material visible to camera, but transparent for all other rays. A light path node is used as mix factor in a mix shader node for this.

Then use a normal environment texture in the world.

[image]

If you have a real skybox texture then use it on the world as enviroment along with another texture to light the scene, and use a light path node to control the visibility. The camera will see one background, but the scene will be lit by the other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my Skybox isn't a background usable with Environment texture. It's a mesh, with different texture and layer (clouds and other stuff animated).

I just want to exclude this object from blocking light.

My question title got edited and doesn't mean the same thing as what i'm asking now

Comment: See edited answer